# GitLab CI/CD artifact exclude not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, artifact

the artifact section of my .gitlab-ci.yml file is:

```
  script:
    - echo "creating artifact"    
  artifacts:
    name: "<name of my project>"
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    exclude:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/deploy/*
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/git/*
```

However, the files i want to be excluded are still included; both the deploy folder and the .git folder and their contents are present when I download the artifact from git. I also get this warning when running the artifact stage of my pipeline, despite git being excluded: `WARNING: Part of .git directory is on the list of files to archive` . I have tried changing it from `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/git/*` to `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.git/*`, but this makes the artifact even larger (so large that the pipeline fails and i can't download the artifact).

I have also tried removing the /* from the filepaths and also changing it to /**/*, but neither solved the issue. One very strage thing is that sometimes the artifact is smaller with the first path ending, and sometimes it is smaller when it is removed.

How can i resolve this so that the correct files are excluded and the artifact is not as large? Or is there anything else I can do to make the artifact smaller?

Comment: These are glob patterns, not regex, so I think you want `/**` not `/*`

Comment: Why are you trying to store the whole project directory as an artifact? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A good practice is to whitelist resources you want to include as artifacts instead of including everything and blacklisting what you want to exclude.

Answer (score 6):

Both the folder itself and its content must be excluded. Only this worked for me:

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - ./
  exclude:
    - .git
    - .git/**/*
```

The result from GitLab job log:

```
...
Uploading artifacts...
./: found 9924 matching files and directories      
.git: excluded 1 files                             
.git/**/*: excluded 31 files
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I discovered that the paths in `exclude` need to be relative to `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` so you have to remove that part from the exclude path.

The final working way is:

```
  script:
    - echo "creating artifact"    
  artifacts:
    name: "<name of my project>"
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    exclude:
      - deploy/**/*
      - .git/**/*
```

Comment: Just tried, it's the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a deeper insights of the use of `exclude` keyword [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#exclude-files-from-job-artifacts) in the **GitLab Doc**. As you'll see in the doc:

> Unlike `artifacts:paths`, `exclude` paths are not recursive. To exclude all of the contents of a directory, match them explicitly rather than matching the directory itself.

So your `.gitlab-ci.yml` should look like :

```
  script:
     - echo "creating artifact"    
  artifacts:
     name: "<name of my project>"
     paths:
       - $CI_PROJECT_DIR
     exclude:
       - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/deploy/**/*
       - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/git/**/*
```

Comment: as I said in my post : "I have also tried removing the /* from the filepaths and also changing it to /**/*, but neither solved the issue."

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply missed the dot (.) in the name of the git directory. Also, as stated in other answers, use the glob syntax:

```
exclude:
  - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.git/**/*
```

Comment: like i said in my post, I already tried both of those and neither worked. I ended up just white listing instead of black listing.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to exclude e.g. `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` at the same time you can use another wildcard match:

```yaml
    exclude:
      - .git/**
      - .git*
```

The first line will skip the content of the `.git` directory, the second line will skip said directory and all Git files like `.gitignore`.